# Nvidia Driver dependency issues for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia

RE-EDIT:
I think I may have installed more than one version of nvidia-driver with some being incompatible with my system. I getting a bunch if complications. When I try to `sudo apt upgrade`. I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-470 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-470 but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-470:i386 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-470 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-470 (= 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-470:i386 (= 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I did as I was told: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 370884 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-470_470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-470'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-470_470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-470:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-470_470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-470'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-470_470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-470_470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-470_470.161.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I the try `sudo apt autoremove nvidia*`

```
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-470 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-470 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-470:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt purge nvidia*` gives this same dead end. How do I fix these dependency issues and remove any multiple nvidia driver versions casuing the trouble? I'd be grateful for any help.

I looked up my "Software&Updates"-->"Other Software", I have some PPAs but don't know what to remove:
[image: Software & Updates--> Other Software]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EoL in April so there's really no point in troubleshooting. I suggest you install fresh the current LTS, 22.04, do NOT add any PPA for drivers as I suspect you did here, and simply open Additional Drivers, select & apply the recommended Nvidia driver version.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I can't abandon ubuntu 18.04 at this moment. Is there any way at all to  troubleshoot?

Comment: Remove any graphics drivers PPA that you added, purge nvidia, reinstall nvidia.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I already tried `sudo apt purge nvidia*`. Unless you mean something else? I'm not sure what you mean by PPA, I'll look that up.

Comment: Open Software & Updates > Other software. All 3rd party repositories (PPAs and others) should be listed there. Regardless of removing the PPA I suspect was added you should try the suggestion in the error message then do the rest.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I added the picture of my "Software&Updates" to my Question. I see some PPAs but not sure what to remove. Also, as I mentioned in my question. I already tried what what the error messages suggested, they did not help.

Comment: As expected, the "graphics-drivers" PPA is there.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not sure exactly what to do. The ppa is  check-marked. Do I uncheck-mark it and click "remove"?

Comment: Either will do but yes, you can remove it because it isn't necessary for the driver version you need and never was. Confirm to refresh when closing then try `sudo apt full-upgrade` as it may, hopefully, fix it. If not then you created an impossible situation.